# Is it possible to run android application from android application?

Tags: android, android-intent, react-native

Is it possible to run android application from android application? For example, i have a button in application 1 and when i press that button i want application 2 to start. I'm developing application in react-native.

I tried with Linking component but I'm getting this error "No Activity found to handle Intent". So i tried to edit AndroidManifest.xml, also without much success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes through Intent we call Activity of another application like below Intent by passing Application Package name and its class name with full package name .

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.MyExampleActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

[Allowing Other Apps to Start Your Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)

Comment: I found this answer on other posts, but problem with react-native is that code is basically javascript and your answer is java native code. I tried to edit react-native files, but without success.